# Why should they be thankful that it's not red?

Tags: the-last-witch-hunter

In Action Fantasy movie, *The Last Witch Hunter (2015)*, Dolan 37th says to Kalduer when he sees Kalduer's car:

[image]

> Dolan 37TH: Uh...I guess we should be thankful it's not red.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the point is that the fancy sports car (an Aston Martin Rapide) is fairly conspicuous, which is not what Dolan wants.  However, he admits the situation could be worse; it could have been bright red, not black.

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously meant to be sarcasm or being flabbergasted that the immortal highly-experienced killer employed by the church would use a car that doesn't helps at all to maintain secrecy.

Comment: You're not wrong, but I don't think this really adds anything to Buzz's answer.